# Good tutorial on uploading images using a mongoDB (mongoid)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, carrierwave

I've set up an application using mongoDB (mongoid) where I'm logging users in with omniauth-twitter.

I need people to be able to upload images, but I can't find any good tutorials for doing this on a mongoDB. I've looked far and wide, but nobody seems to have made one yet.

Do you have any links?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can go to [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) for Rails tutorials. The one I linked to explains paperclip ,doubt it will explain using it with mongoid.

Comment: Ya... that's the big thing for me. Why isn't there any good tutorials for uploading files with a mongoDB? There's also a tutorial for carrierwave - http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads -  but I don't know how I set it up to use mongoid instead of sqlite. Any quick recommendations?

Comment: Here's one I've found.  http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is here. Carrierwave handles mongoid through [carrierwave-mongoid](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid). If it doesn't suit you, `paperclip` handles mongoid, too, without hassle.

Comment: Problem is I'm a bit of a noob, so I need a step to step guide on how to do it, from start, till generating files, to finished app. You don't know any good tutorials?

Comment: Nope, I don't. I don't think it's much different than the Active Record version though, I mean, it's kind of the point after all. I only used paperclip, and it was easier to set up on mongoid, since there is no migration and stuff.